# What's the name of the tools or software used to edit the pictures like this?

Tags: image

Who can tell me **what tools or software** are used to edit the pictures like this
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/ASPDOTNETPageLifecycle/1.jpg 
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/ASPDOTNETPageLifecycle/2.jpg ?

If you can tell me I would be very grateful.

Comment: Hello. Unfortunately, this site is for software-development purposes.

Comment: You can do that kinda thing with paint, word, excel...! you don't need  special software for that!!

Comment: Looks like http://www.balsamiq.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the Balsamiq tool:
http://builds.balsamiq.com/b/mockups-web-demo/